# Facebook sdk error in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

I have used the facebook new sdk for getting the information of user. But when i run on device it gives me the error like "The Operation couldn't be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)." And also i have signed in facebook from device setting.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Go to the settings app of your iPhone.
Open your Facebook Settings

**Scroll down to your app and make sure your app allows facebook
   interaction.**

---

This could happen on any device, therefore in your app you will have to make sure to handle this error correctly. I reckon you give the user feedback why Login With Facebook failed and ask the user to check their Facebook settings on their device.

```
- (void)facebookSessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState)state error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            // handle successful login here
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

            if (error) {
                // handle error here, for example by showing an alert to the user
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Could not login with Facebook"
                                                                message:@"Facebook login failed. Please check your Facebook settings on your phone."
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your bundle identifier and make sure that it is same as you have entered on https://developers.facebook.com/ while registering you app.

Comment: yes i have use the same identifier in facebook and in app